# Eliminating a footer popup in Joomla

Tags: joomla

Although I'm from [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), I need to make a slight change on an old Joomla Website for a friend of mine.

The site is: http://aja-architekten.de

I need to eliminate the footer Popup which says "Wir sind umgezogen".

I know there might be a thousand ways to implement this in Joomla, but what is the plugin or module in the code!

Comment: Joomla questions should always be posted on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to identify without back-end access to the website as it could be a module, a plugin, or even hard coded into the `index.php` file of the template or similar.

If it's not obvious, the easiest work around might be to add some code to a custom CSS file like this or similar:

```
#ca_banner {
    display: none !important;
}
```

To create a custom CSS file using a Warp theme, create `custom.css` in the /css subfolder in the relevant template folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the insight! I created the file and added your CSS but still the footer popup appears. Any more ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't look like the CSS file is loading. Try clearing the Joomla cache. If it still does not load, consult the documentation for the template you are using to find out how to add custom CSS. Alternatively, you could use a third party extension to add custom CSS such as the free extension at https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/add-custom-css or similar

Comment: The custom.css file already existed and I just added your code. Since there is also other stuff inside this file I suppose it works... But still I cant figure out why this popup appears...

Comment: I can't see where the custom CSS is being loaded but that may be because of JCH Optimise. Try: `#absolute {display: none !important;}` instead.

Comment: Doesnt work either - can I somehow deactivate JCH optimise? What is that anyways? :-)

Comment: JCH Optimize is a performance extension which aggregates and minifies css and javascript files.

Comment: Hi Matthias, it looks like you managed to fix the issue. Please share the solution by adding a new answer and mark your answer as accepted so we can all learn how this was resolved.

Comment: Hi - sorry for the delay. I managed to contact the initial developer and he fixed it by manually deactivating a plugin in the myadmin backend. He didn't tell me which one however.